# Changing text inside upload button after uploading

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
<div className='file-upload-wrapper' data-text='Select your file!'>
            <input
              type='file'
              id='upload'
              className='file-upload-field'
              placeholder='Enter Item Name'
              required
              onChange={(e) => setUpload(e.target.value)}
              onClick={changeUploadTxt}
            ></input>
          </div>
```

The CSS for this:

```
.file-upload-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
}

.file-upload-wrapper::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 20;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #999;
  border-radius: 5px 10px 10px 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.file-upload-wrapper::before {
  content: "Upload";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  background: #4daf7c;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  z-index: 25;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.file-upload-wrapper::hover {
  background: darken(#4daf7c, 40%);
}
```

I was trying to do something with this, but it didn't worked:

```
const changeUploadTxt = () => {
    //const txtDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("file-upload-wrapper");
  };
```

I also changed the CSS content with before and after, but it didn't worked. Do you know a method for making sure that files are uploaded and change the text after inside the div tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how React works.  Don't think of it in terms of directly manipulating the DOM in an event handler.  Instead, think of it in terms of *managing state*.

- The render operation displays a state value
- The event updates the state value

So in the start of your component (assuming a function component, since that's the preferred approach for new development at this time) you might declare a state value:

```
const [uploadText, setUploadText] = useState('Select your file!');
```

Then you'd use that value in your rendering:

```
<div className='file-upload-wrapper' data-text={uploadText}>
```

Now all you have to do is update the state value any time you want it to change:

```
const changeUploadTxt = () => {    
  setUploadText('Some new value');
};
```

Any time you update state, that will trigger the component to re-render.  Which is also why you *don't* directly manipulate the DOM in React (unless you *really* know what you're doing under the hood in the framework), because a re-render will break whatever changes you made to the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

you can use innerHtml for adding a text.

```
const changeUploadTxt = () => {    
    document.getElementsByClassName("file-upload-wrapper").innerHTML += "Upload";
};
```

Comment: Nothing changed, I also tried that earlier with textContent and innerHTML but nothing changes.

Comment: Directly manipulating the DOM in React is *almost always* the wrong approach.

Comment: Ohh, It is in react. sorry its my bed. This is for JavaScript

Comment: Seems like there's no way to do that with an `<input type="file">` since the element that has the `text node` is inside the **ShadowDOM** of the `<input>` and `<input>` elements don't allow to change the ShadowDOM. I suggest to you to create your own file input. The authorized elements to manipulate ShadowDOM are: `<article>, <aside>, <blockquote>, <body>, <div>, <footer>, <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>, <header>, <main>, <nav>, <p>, <section> or <span>`